# will bigbluebutton work on ubuntu 11.10?while installing getting error

Tags: php, ruby, bigbluebutton

I am trying to install bigbluebutton in ubuntu 11.10 system when i use the command

wget http://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/bigbluebutton.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
i am getting the error as

--2012-03-07 10:10:42--  (try:19)  http://ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org/bigbluebutton.asc
Connecting to ubuntu.bigbluebutton.org|134.117.48.101|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.

Atlast am getting the error as  gpg no valid openpgp data found.

will bigbluebutton work on ubuntu 11.10?

can anyone suggest me the answer for this

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the file separately. Once you have a good copy of it, from the directory that contains it, just do: `sudo apt-key add bigbluebutton.asc`.

Comment: am getting the same error while retrieving the files also and atlast am getting the command as gpg no valid openpgp data found

Answer (score 0):

Try to set up a [gpg key](http://quantumlab.net/pine_privacy_guard/howto_setup_gpg.html) then you try the previous step after this

Answer (score 0):

It will not work on Ubuntu 11.10.

We have an [updated installation](http://docs.bigbluebutton.org/install/install.html) of **BigBlueButton 0.9.0** for Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit.